# "gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device" on GitHub actions

Tags: maven, github, github-actions, gpg-signature

I am trying to automatize the deployment of a java library to nexus ossrh with GitHub. I created the following `release.yml`:

```yaml
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          server-id: ossrh
          settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }}
          gpg-private-key: ${{ secrets.GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          gpg-passphrase: ${{ secrets.GPG_PASSPHRASE }}
          server-username: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_USERNAME }}
          server-password: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Verify package
        run: mvn clean verify

      - name: Publish package
        run: mvn clean deploy -P release -DskipTests

      - name: Commit and push release
        run: |
          git add pom.xml target/*.jar
          git commit -m "Release ${VERSION}"
          git push
```

my `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>-P release</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.13</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                            <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                            <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-sources</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.13</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                            <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                            <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

When I try to deploy manually from my PC using `mvn clean deploy` it is asking me for my gpg passphrase eventhough I have it registered in my `settings.xml` but at least the deployement is working.
`settings.xml`:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

        <servers>
            <server>
                <id>ossrh</id>
                <username>my_username</username>
                <password>my_pass</password>
            </server>
        </servers>
        
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>ossrh</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>  
                </activation>
                <properties>
                    <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
                    <gpg.passphrase>my_pass</gpg.passphrase>
                </properties> 
            </profile>
        </profiles>
        
    </settings>
```

The error I am getting in GitHib action is as follows:

```
...
[INFO] Signing 4 files with default secret key.
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.914 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-21T22:14:50Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.1.0:sign (sign-artifacts) on project SomeProjectName: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to add a `setting.xml` file in `.github/workflows/` directory and to change the run in `release.yml` to `run: mvn clean deploy -P release -DskipTests --settings .github/workflows/settings.xml` but I'm still getting the same error.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error "`gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`" usually means that GPG is trying to open a [`pinentry` dialog](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/pinentry/index.html) to get the passphrase, but in a headless environment (like GitHub Actions), this dialog cannot be displayed.

So you should configure GPG to use a [loopback mode](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-OPTION.html) for passphrase input.
See for illustration "[Using Command-Line Passphrase Input for GPG with Git (for Windows)](https://betakuang.medium.com/using-command-line-passphrase-input-for-gpg-with-git-for-windows-f78ae2c7cd2e)" by [betakuang/人生リセット](https://twitter.com/betakuang).

Modify your `release.yml` to configure GPG to use loopback mode. Add a step before the `Publish package` step:

```yaml
- name: Prepare GPG
run: |
     echo "allow-loopback-pinentry" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
     gpgconf --reload gpg-agent
```

Make sure that the GPG key and passphrase are correctly set up in your GitHub Actions secrets and referenced in the `release.yml`.
And make sure your `settings.xml` is correctly referencing the GPG passphrase. That seems to be already done in your configuration.

Update your `pom.xml` and `release.yml` accordingly, and then push these changes to trigger the GitHub Action again.

Your `release.yml` should be:

```yaml
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          server-id: ossrh
          settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }}
          gpg-private-key: ${{ secrets.GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          gpg-passphrase: ${{ secrets.GPG_PASSPHRASE }}
          server-username: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_USERNAME }}
          server-password: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Prepare GPG
        run: |
          echo "allow-loopback-pinentry" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
          gpgconf --reload gpg-agent

      - name: Verify package
        run: mvn clean verify

      - name: Publish package
        run: mvn clean deploy -P release -DskipTests

      - name: Commit and push release
        run: |
          git add pom.xml target/*.jar
          git commit -m "Release ${VERSION}"
          git push
```